# How to display a search result page in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have 2 extension points for a search page (which successfully renders) and a search results page (which doesn't render).

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.search.searchPages">
   <page id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaSearchPage"
        icon="icons/full/obj16/jsearch_obj.png"
        label="%JavaSearchPage.label"
        sizeHint="460,160"
        extensions="java:90, jav:90"
        showScopeSection="true"
        canSearchEnclosingProjects="true"
        class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.search.JavaSearchPage">
    </page>
</extension>
```

```
<extension
    id="JavaSearchResultPage"
    point="org.eclipse.search.searchResultViewPages">
    <viewPage
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaSearchResultPage"
        searchResultClass="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.search.JavaSearchResult"
        class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.search.JavaSearchResultPage">
    </viewPage>
</extension>
```

Of course, the classes which I have are (not the Java default ones) have been put in the xml.
I have a class SomethingSearchPage which: `extends DialogPage implements ISearchPage` and has a `createControl()` and `performAction()` which both seem to work since the actual search page renders and the `performAction()` is called when I hit the search button.

The problem is: I cannot get a results page in any way!

I have 2 classes for the result: `SomethingSearchResult extends AbstractTextSearchResult` and `SomethingSearchResultPage extends AbstractTextSearchViewPage`. Do I need a View and a Content Provider? How can I connect these the search result page actually renders?

Comment: Yes you have to completely set up the given tree viewer in configureTreeViewer, and a table viewer in configureTableViewer. Look at something like the standard file search results page `org.eclipse.search.internal.ui.text.FileSearchPage`

Comment: What would completely mean? Set the content provider and the label provider for the Viewer? The `FileSearchPage` is very complex and big, much more than what I would need at the moment.

Comment: Viewers always need a content provider and almost always a label provider,

Comment: I have done that but I still have the problem of the result page not rendering when the actual search button is clicked. I see that the search okay (I print it out in the console for myself) but the search page closes and that's it. Do you have any idea of why this could happen?

Comment: This is quite a complex API which I haven't looked at in a long time, any number of things might not be right. I suggest you use debug to see what the search view is doing - `org.eclipse.search2.internal.ui.SearchView`, maybe the `internalShowSearchPage` method.